# in the .net core,it has Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Application Project Deployment?

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, publish

Like this(this is asp.net web The program):

[image]

Comment: I want to modify the web.config content when the project is building

Comment: Use the environmental variables and different config files for each of environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While web.config transforms are still an option, Asp.Net Core seems to be moving away from them for application-level configuration and instead using things like environment variables and config.json files.

For the JSON configuration file option, you are able to create multiple JSON files for each environment, and use an environment variable at runtime to determine which file is loaded.  More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration